# C++ Bessel function for complex numbers

Tags: c++, numbers, numerical-methods

I want to implement the Bessel functions of first and second kind[Description of bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind_%3a_J.CE.B1) for complex numbers in C++. Now I am looking for possibilities to introduce them in my source code. Since math.h only contains bessel functions for real numbers, I would be interested in seeing any kind of possibility.

Comment: `http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html`

Comment: what are Bessel functions?!

Comment: Can you implement them with real numbers?

Comment: No, but math.h has them. you get them with jn(unsigned int, double x) and yn(unsigned int, double x)

Comment: So you may need a function which describes complex Bessel function in terms of real bessel or other funcions. Can you describe the function in this way?

Comment: Although your first sentence sounds right, I do not understand your question.

Comment: suppose f(x+iy) is the compex bessel function. Can you find real functions g(x,y) and h(x,y) with f(x+iy)=g(x,y)+ih(x,y)?

Comment: if I could, then I had solved my problem..

Comment: well, now you have a math problem. I suggest to ask this in math.SE.

Comment: You can look at an implementation of Bessel functions in any open source math library such as glibc. Porting one to the complex case would (hopefully!) consist of replacing `double` with `std::complex<double>` and compiling with a C++ compiler. Use your understanding of maths to refine the process. If you need this for work, consult your legal department first.

Comment: In that wiki page I see a series you can also approximate the value of the series in a function. Also see if the `<complex>` header file has this fuctions predefined.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found that Boost is compatible with complex arguments (though it may a mistake on my part).

The FORTRAN code developed by D.E. Amos (the code used by MATLAB and others) is in the [public domain](http://netlib.org/amos/) and can be used by anybody. I have been developing a C++ interface to the library, extending it to the case of negative orders. You can check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/valandil/complex_bessel).

Answer (score 1):

The [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/) implements ordinary Bessel functions of the first and second kind and modified Bessel functions of the first and second kind for both real and complex numbers (see [documentation about Bessel functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/bessel/bessel_over.html)).

[Don't try to reinvent the wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel), just use the Boost implementation which is far superior to anything you could write yourself.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case. I haven't been able to compile something like `std::cout << boost::math::cyl_bessel_j<double, std::complex<double> > (0.0,std::complex<double>(1.0,0.0)) << std::endl;` with Boost.

Comment: Indeed, they don't seem to support complex arguments, if [this discussion](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/no-subject-td4478639.html) still represents current state.